# Recording X windows events

Tags: x11

I am a novice when it comes to X windows but have some knowledge of Unix as such.

My project requires me to track user input and output on X window system. For instance, if the GUI is used to configure a route, I would like to know what application is used and what route has been configured. So far, I have explored the following options with partial success.

1)Tried to hook functions like XDrawString and XDrawText using LD_PRELOAD.
2)Used xwininfo to obtain window id and tools like xev.
3)Looked through similar discussions in this forum especially on xev and xinput

1)May not work with if X11 is statically linked? Not sure.
2)xev does not record key press events for a file edited with gedit or attempting to rename a file from the GUI
3)I am trying to go through X windows system internals.

I am pretty discouraged so far. Any input/pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: 1) not all x11 applications use xlib. To intercept ALL events you'll need to listen at network level ( tcpdump / libpcap )

Comment: You want to create a pretty sophisticated AI. X11 interface is easily the most trivial of the challenges you are facing. XDrawString and friends won't help you (neither on the LD_PRELOAD level nor on the tcpdump level) because almost no one is using this part of the protocol these days. Characters are drawn client-side and pushed to the server as bitmaps. You will have to OCR the pixels if you want to know what text is on the screen.

Comment: Would xlib hooks be of any use?  I guess it wont always because as per Andrey xlib may not be used always.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the cnee program from the Xnee project, which uses the X window system Record extension.  The examples that I see for cnee are almost always about recording input events, but, according to the Xnee manual at https://xnee.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/xnee1.pdf, section 3.2.1 ("Record"), "Xnee can record the whole X11 protocol, not just mouse and keyboard events."

Regarding font operations, I believe that X font facilities, mostly through the X font server, evolved over time too, so it might be the case that the applications that you care about are doing X font operations which you can trace.